# Protrcator - Returns empty array after the function call

Tags: selenium, protractor

I just need what error am doing in below protractor function. I am getting array as empty. The code is  below

```
function(){
        var arrVal=[];
        elem = element.all(by.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"header-col")]/div'));
        elem.each(function(elementVar) {
          elementVar.getAttribute('title').then(function(val){
            arrVal.push(val.toString());
          });
        });
        console.log(arrVal.len);
    }
```

Comment: did you check to see if `elementVar.getAttribute('title')` returns anything before pushing that value to the array?

Comment: Yup @Gunderson its priniting the values

Answer (score 2):

`element.all()` returns an [ElementArrayFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder).  As per the description, this can be treated as an array of webElements and you can perform actions on each element in that array.

So for your case, you don't need to create your own array.  You can just return an array of elements that has `getAttribute` called on it, this will return an array of the values retrieved:

```
function(){
    // this could be all one line, but wanted it to fit:
    let list = element.all(by.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"header-col")]/div'))
    return list.getAttribute('title');
}
// example return value: ['Welcome', 'Homepage', 'About']
```

Note: this is returning a promise, so you will have to call `.then` when using this function unless placed within an `expect` (resolves promises on its own)

Comment: @RufusLawrence Did this work for you?  Please consider accepting the answer if its correct to help others

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the promise by using .then and push each attribute in the array

```
 function(callback){
            var arrVal=[];
            elem = element.all(by.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"header-col")]/div'));

            elem.then(function(arrayElements){
               for(i=0; i<arrayElements.length ;i++){
                  arrVal[i] = arrayElements[i].getAttribute('title');
               }
               callback(arrVal);
             });

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise in this case:

```
function(){
    var arrVal=[];
    elem = element.all(by.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"header-col")]/div'));
    elem.each((elementVar) => {
        return elementVar.getAttribute('title').then(val => arrVal.push(val.toString()));
    });
    console.log(arrVal.len);
}
```